# How to query a pandas dataframe for a specific attribute

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame of provinces and average finish times in a race for people from each province.

I would like to query the dataset for the name of the province with the lowest average time.

My data frame looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Did an answer below help? Feel free to accept an answer (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df.loc[df['Finish'] == df['Finish'].min()]
```

If you want *only* the name of the province (*i.e.* the index), try this:

```
df.loc[df['Finish'] == df['Finish'].min()].index[0]
```

Comment: perfect thank you, i had figured out the first part it was finding only the name which I was having trouble with, this solved it easily

Answer (score 0):

You can query with ... `df.query`:

```
res = df.query('Finish == Finish.min()')
```

You can get names of these province(s) by chaining `.index`.

Answer (score 0):

see this code...

```
import pandas as pd

d = [
{"name":  "name 10", "value":1},
{"name":  "name 2", "value":2},
{"name":  "name 3", "value":3}]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)

print(df.min()["name"])
```